# I want to combine numerical value and text (commenting on an value)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I’ve a value eg: 3,100,000.24 in a cell, which I want to mention in comments automatically.

Eg: Increase in xx by 3.1MM

I tried using formula:

```
="Decrese in X by "&TEXT(J22,"[<999950]0.0,"K";[<999950000]0.0,,"M";0.0,,,"B"")
```

However, it gives me an error.

Can someone please help me on this.

Issue is related to excel.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You will need vba for this.

Comment: To correct your formula syntax, try: `="Decrese in X by "&TEXT(A1,"[<999950]0.0,\K;[<999950000]0.0,,\M;0.0,,\B")` as it will not give an error. Whether it provides your desired result is something only you can determine since your formula does not match your **Eg** statement

Comment: I assume that "Decrease" v "Increase" is a  beside-the-point typo. @Ron Rosenfeld - your correction seems to work up to 310M but for ten times that, shows me 3100.0B - I think we need three commas rather than two before the \B ?

Comment: @zsalya I was only examining the syntax of his formula. The missing comma in my example is present in the OP's example. As you put it, it was a "beside-the-point" typo. I would have gone further had he provided an mcve; and I would think the conditionals probably should be changed, depending on what he really wants to do with those edge cases.

Comment: @findwindow It doesn't look to me as though VBA is relevant, and certainly not necessary.

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld. I completely agree. I was just thinking about what will happen when somebody finds this in 5 years time, misses the subtlety of your second sentence and copies the formula! Thank you for the fact that I have today learnt about those commas in TEXT.

Comment: @zsalya `want to mention in comments automatically`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get what you want to do, but in `TEXT(J22,"[<999950]0.0,"K"` the quotes before `K` matches the one before `[<999950]0.0,`, closing the text and leaving your `K` is loose in the formula. Similar thing with the `M` and `B`.